# HTML textarea's text direction change messing up tag structure with % sign

Tags: html, textarea, special-characters, right-to-left

I have a sms editor created with textarea, where you can add text and pre defined custom tag like %%voucher?id=1%%.

[image: tag in LTR direction]

```
<textarea dir="ltr">%%voucher?id=1%%</textarea>
```

My problem is when the text direction is changed , this tag becoms voucher?id=1%%%%.  this is messing up the tag structure.

[image: tag in RTl direction]

```
<textarea dir="rtl">%%voucher?id=1%%</textarea>
```

I tried this in tinyMCE and CKEditor, both have same behaviour when customised to work as sms editor.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Provide the code here. How can someone help without the code?

Comment: There is nothing much of the code. its just toggling between the _dir_ attribute of textarea. lets say <textarea dir="rtl">%%voucher?id=1%%</textarea>

Comment: Are you trying to toggle text direction or text alignment?

Comment: @SanaMumtaz,  text direction. to write Arabic text.

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of invisible control character `&lrm;` to preserve the direction.

```html
<textarea dir="ltr">%%voucher?id=1&lrm;%%</textarea>
<textarea dir="rtl">%%voucher?id=1&lrm;%%</textarea>
```

For conditionally adding `&lrm;`, you'll need to parse the textarea value. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236540/inserting-ltr-marks-automatically) will help.

Comment: This is a good soultion if we dont allow changing the content of the textarea. The  tag will get mutilated the moment something enterd on the same line.